# How to get underlying event in Esper

Tags: java, events, esper

I have created a listener implementing UpdateListener interface, which is attached to an Event (Example - TestEvent). Now every time this event is raised, I want to get the underlying event for TestEvent and print that.

Example:

**Statement 1**  -

on ParentEvent1
insert into TestEvent

**Statement 2** -

on ParentEvent2
insert into TestEvent

**Statement 3** -

on ParentEvent3
insert into TestEvent

**Statement 4**  -

on ParentEvent4
insert into TestEvent

So whenever TestEvent is raised, I need to print "TestEvent is raised because of ParentEvent4","TestEvent is raised because of ParentEvent1" etc.

Thanks,
Regards,
Ankit Jain

Answer (score 0):

This is done by selecting some information regarding the triggering event itself from the stream.

```
on ParentEvent1 as p1 insert into TestEvent select p1, somemoreinformation from MyNamedWindow
```

Instead of selecting the event itself its also fine to select some text:

```
on P1 insert into TestEvent select 'P1' as triggeredBy from ...
on P2 insert into TestEvent select 'P2' as triggeredBy from ...
```